# What are the difference between NGINX Plus and NGINX Community edition? Some doubts in the use of NGINX in the WSO2 EI cluster creation

Tags: nginx, wso2, cluster-computing, load-balancing, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am absolutly new in NGINX and I have the following doubts about this product.
I have to create a WSO2 EI cluster and reading the official documentation it says to use **NGINIX** as **load balancer**:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile#ClusteringtheESBProfile-Configuringtheloadbalancer

On the official documentation it is specified that:

> Follow the steps below to configure NGINX Plus version 1.7.11 or NGINX
>   community version 1.9.2 as the load balancer.

So the first doubt: what is the difference between **NGINX Plus** and **NGINX Community**? Is the first the payment version and the second a free version?

In case my assertion is correct what are the limitation in the use of the community edition?

Another doubt is that going on the NGNIX website: 
https://www.nginx.com/solutions/adc/

it seems to me that it offers different products (from load balancer to web server and other stuff). Is it a single product doing more jobs or is it composed by different modules that have to be installed separately?

Another doubt is: basing on the amount of traffic that the load balancer have to handle changes the hardware requirements of the VM where I have to install it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the first the payment version and the second a free version?

Basically - yes. Plus additional features.

NGINX Plus as well suports out of box sticky sessions needed for HA setup for carbon console, active service healthcheck and more. I needed the two mentioned.

In theory you could build (compile) additional addon modules (e. g. for sticky sessions and healthchecks) with the community edition too, but it's not always working as smoothly as I expected. (you may as well consider Apache httpd)

It may worth to have support at hand, mainly for critical deployments. I prefer this solution, rather than clients calling me during weekends to check my custom builds.

> Is it a single product doing more jobs or is it composed by different modules that have to be installed separately?

NGINX offers more products (APIM, WAF,..) as far I know it's all the NGINX Plus with additional modules. But for load balancing you may be ok with basic web server (load balancer) and keepalived

> Another doubt is.. changes the hardware requirements of the VM where I have to install it?

NGINX can handle A LOT of traffic even on modest infrastructure, much more than the wso2ei itself, imho  nginx won't be your bottleneck until you don't do anything special (WAF) or stupid (log payloads)

Comment: Thank you for your precise information. I have only 2 doubs: what do you mean with "HA sertup for carbon console"? It is not clear for me if I can use the community edition to implement my WSO2 cluster environment. Reading the official documentation it seems that I can use both version but I am not sure about it

Comment: @AndreaNobili you can use any version for the cluster environment (commercial or oss), even any load balancer you want (apache httpd, f5, HAProxy, ..). I believe WSO2 docs mention the nginx explicitly, because it's popular and WSO2 resales the Nginx Plus licences too.  To have load-balanced carbon (admin) console, you need sticky sessions, but imho that is not critical.

Comment: Hi @gusto. Why is it not critical? because I can point directly to a specific Carbon node to access the admin panel? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AndreaNobili Yes, I meant that you can point to a node directly for the carbon console.